# How can I merge multiple dataframes with the same column names?

Tags: r, join, merge, dataframe

#### What I have:

I have a "master" dataframe that has the following columns:

```
userid, condition
```

Since there are four experiment conditions, I also have four dataframes that carry answer information, with the following columns:

```
userid, condition, answer1, answer2
```

Now, I'd like to join these, so all combinations of user IDs, conditions and their answers to these conditions are merged. Each condition should only have the correct answer in the appropriate column, per row.

---

#### Short, self-contained example:

```
master = data.frame(userid=c("foo","foo","foo","foo","bar","bar","bar","bar"), condition=c("A","B","C","D","A","B","C","D"))
cond_a = data.frame(userid=c("foo","bar"), condition="A", answer1=c("1","1"), answer2=c("2","2"))
cond_b = data.frame(userid=c("foo","bar"), condition="B", answer1=c("3","3"), answer2=c("4","4"))
cond_c = data.frame(userid=c("foo","bar"), condition="C", answer1=c("5","5"), answer2=c("6","6"))
cond_d = data.frame(userid=c("foo","bar"), condition="D", answer1=c("7","7"), answer2=c("8","8"))
```

How do I merge all conditions into the master, so the master table looks like follows?

```
  userid condition answer1 answer2
1    bar         A       1       2
2    bar         B       3       4
3    bar         C       5       6
4    bar         D       7       8
5    foo         A       1       2
6    foo         B       3       4
7    foo         C       5       6
8    foo         D       7       8
```

I've tried the following:

```
temp = merge(master, cond_a, all.x=TRUE)
```

Which gives me:

```
  userid condition answer1 answer2
1    bar         A       1       2
2    bar         B    <NA>    <NA>
3    bar         C    <NA>    <NA>
4    bar         D    <NA>    <NA>
5    foo         A       1       2
6    foo         B    <NA>    <NA>
7    foo         C    <NA>    <NA>
8    foo         D    <NA>    <NA>
```

But as soon as I do this…

```
merge(temp, cond_b, all.x=TRUE)
```

There are no values for condition `B`. How come?

```
  userid condition answer1 answer2
1    bar         A       1       2
2    bar         B    <NA>    <NA>
3    bar         C    <NA>    <NA>
4    bar         D    <NA>    <NA>
5    foo         A       1       2
6    foo         B    <NA>    <NA>
7    foo         C    <NA>    <NA>
8    foo         D    <NA>    <NA>
```

Comment: I just noticed I could do `merge(temp, cond_b, all=TRUE)`, but that'd give me extra rows with `NA`s in it. Not ideal.

Comment: Would this help?
`temp <-rbind(cond_a,cond_b,cond_c,cond_d)
    temp[order(temp["userid"]),]`
Or is there something specific as a relationship with contents in master?

Comment: In the simple case of this post, yes indeed! I have a few extra columns in the master, which is why it doesn't work in my specific dataset – but I didn't mention that, so feel free to post that as an example as well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `Reduce()` and `complete.cases()` as follows:

```
merged <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all=TRUE), 
                 list(master, cond_a, cond_b, cond_c, cond_d))
merged[complete.cases(merged), ]
#    userid condition answer1 answer2
# 1     bar         A       1       2
# 2     bar         B       3       4
# 4     bar         C       5       6
# 6     bar         D       7       8
# 8     foo         A       1       2
# 9     foo         B       3       4
# 11    foo         C       5       6
# 13    foo         D       7       8
```

`Reduce()` might take some getting accustomed to. You define your function, and then provide a `list` of objects to repeatedly apply the function to. Thus, that statement is like doing:

```
temp1 <- merge(master, cond_a, all=TRUE)
temp2 <- merge(temp1, cond_b, all=TRUE)
temp3 <- merge(temp2, ....)
```

Or something like:

```
merge(merge(merge(master, cond_a, all=TRUE), cond_b, all=TRUE), cond_c, all=TRUE)
```

`complete.cases()` creates a logical vector of whether the specified columns are "complete" or not; this logical vector can be used to subset from the merged `data.frame`.

Comment: Cool, this works great for my specific example! Now, what would I have to do if `master` data frame included additional columns that I wanted to keep? Basically, I'd just want to assign the answers to the unique `userid` and `condition` pairs.

Comment: So, to be more precise I now get a row with `foo, A, 1, 2, other`, but then subsequently `foo, B, <NA>, <NA>, blah`, which would be removed in the `complete.cases()` step.

Comment: I *think* I got it. When I `rbind` all condition dataframes first and then `merge(master, all_conditions, all.x=TRUE)`, this seems to give me everything.

Answer (score 2):

As stated by the OP, given that no explicit relationship with the master data frame, an option is this:

```
temp <-rbind(cond_a,cond_b,cond_c,cond_d)
temp[order(temp["userid"]),]
```

Perhaps if any relationship was known, there could be a non-simplistic solution.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "explicit relationship"? Obviously, `userid` and `condition` are factors in the experiment data, while the answer scores are simple numeric items that belong to a certain user and treatment.

Comment: What I meant was that even without the master df, one could arrive at the output you want. So just cond_[a-d] suffices. If there was more relationships (like columns in there) between master & cond_[a-d] then this might be insufficient as a solution

Answer (score 1):

You can express this join as a `SQL` statement, and then use the `sqldf` library to execute it.

```
cond_all = rbind(cond_a, cond_b, cond_c, cond_d)

> sqldf('select p.userid as userid, p.condition as condition, answer1, answer2 from master as p join cond_all as q on p.userid=q.userid and p.condition=q.condition order by userid, condition')
  userid condition answer1 answer2
1    bar         A       1       2
2    bar         B       3       4
3    bar         C       5       6
4    bar         D       7       8
5    foo         A       1       2
6    foo         B       3       4
7    foo         C       5       6
8    foo         D       7       8
```

You mentioned in a comment that the master dataframe has extra columns that do not exist in the cond dataframes. You should be able to modify this SQL query to still work for this case.